# State being reset

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Newbie to React & React hooks. I'm trying to understand why my state is being overwritten by initialState.

When I input a value, things work as expected. However when I resize the window it resets it to the initialState and I'm not sure why.
After inserting values into the inputs `updateBox` displays the correct values.

Can anybody break this down for me as to what is happening?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hdf3sg

```
import React,{useState,useEffect,useRef} from 'react';
import './Layout.scss';

const initLayout = {
  size:{
    width: 16,
    height: 16,
  }
}
const clone = (obj) => {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

const Layout = ({props}) => {

  const boxContainer = useRef(null);

  const [layoutState,setLayoutState] = useState(initLayout)
  const [boxStyle,setBoxStyle] = useState({
    "height": "100%",
    "width": "90%",
  })

  useEffect(() =>{
    // State did update
    console.log("useEffect:State did update:",layoutState.size.width,":",layoutState.size.height)
    // updateBox()
  });

  useEffect(() =>{
    // Component did mount
    console.log("Component did mount")
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateBox);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", updateBox);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // This state did update
    console.log("layoutState did update",layoutState)
    updateBox()
  }, [layoutState]);

  const updateBox = () => {
    console.log("updateBox",layoutState.size.width,":",layoutState.size.height)

    let percentage = (layoutState.size.height/layoutState.size.width) * 100
    if(percentage > 100){
      percentage = 100
    }
    percentage = percentage+"%"

    // console.log("percentage",percentage)

    const cloneBoxStyle = clone(boxStyle)

    cloneBoxStyle.width = "100%"
    cloneBoxStyle.height = percentage
    setBoxStyle(cloneBoxStyle)

    // console.log("boxContainer",boxContainer)
    // console.log("height",boxContainer.current.clientHeight)
    // console.log("width",boxContainer.current.clientWidth)

  }



  const sizeRatioOnChange = (widthArg,heightArg) => {
    let width = (widthArg === null) ? layoutState.size.width : widthArg;
    let height = (heightArg === null) ? layoutState.size.height : heightArg;

    const cloneLayoutState = clone(layoutState);
    cloneLayoutState.size.width = width
    cloneLayoutState.size.height = height

    setLayoutState(cloneLayoutState)
  }

  const render = () => {
    console.log("render",layoutState.size.width,":",layoutState.size.height)
    // updateBox()
    // const enlargeClass = (true) ? " enlarge" : "" ;

    return (
      <div className={"layout"} >
        <div className="layout-tools-top">
          Layout Size Ratio 
          <input 
            type="number" 
            value={layoutState.size.width} 
            onChange={(e) => {sizeRatioOnChange(e.target.value,null)}}/>
          by
          <input 
            type="number" 
            value={layoutState.size.height} 
            onChange={(e) => {sizeRatioOnChange(null,e.target.value)}}/>

          <button className="button close">
            Close
          </button>
        </div>

        <div className="layout-container">
          <div className="layout-tools-side">
            <h2>Header</h2>
            <ul>

            </ul>
            <form>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Add Item" />
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className="layout-box-container" ref={boxContainer}>
            <div className="layout-box" style={boxStyle}>
              {/* {boxStyle.height} x {boxStyle.width} */}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return render();
};

export default Layout;
```

[image]

Comment: What is rendering `VenueLayout`? Can you show us the code where it is being called?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    // Component did mount
    console.log("Component did mount")
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateBox); //HERE
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", updateBox);
    };
  }, []);
```

the **updateBox** function you are binding to the resize window event will use the state it had at the moment it was bounded (when the component did mount) because the callback of **addEventListener** is executed in its own closure.

To solve this you have to save the state inside a ref, that way it will still be current, also when you are accessing it from another closure.
so first create the ref and store the state in it:

```
const [layoutState,setLayoutState] = useState(initLayout);
const layoutRef= useRef({});
layoutRef.current = layoutState;
```

and then inside the **updateBox** function you have to read the layout "state" from **layoutRef** instead of **layoutState**:

```
  const updateBox = () => {
    let percentage = (layoutRef.current.size.height/layoutRef.current.size.width) * 100
    
    if(percentage > 100){
      percentage = 100
    }
    percentage = percentage+"%"

    const cloneBoxStyle = clone(boxStyle);

    cloneBoxStyle.width = "100%"
    cloneBoxStyle.height = percentage
    setBoxStyle(cloneBoxStyle)
  }
```

Let me know if it works and please give feedback since this is my first answer here :)

Comment: Amazing, yep that was it. I had a feeling that was going on but I had no idea why. Thank you very much for breaking it down for me :)

Comment: thanks Trevor, I had a similar problem like one month ago.. This guy here is also very good at explaining what's happening: https://youtu.be/eTDnfS2_WE4

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for this. I was going mad last night trying to figure out what was going on. As soon as I saw this it clicked!

Comment: 10/10 answer. fixed a bug in my code also!

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your initial state outside of the component or just set it directly.  In your resize function you are setting another state object and it is re-rendering the component but since your initial state is inside the component I think you are just adding it back to the state for every re-render.

Also probably not related to your issue you will probably want to cleanup your resize function or your will more than likely have some issues.  All that said try doing something like the following:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect,useRef} from 'react';
import './VenueLayout.scss';

import {clone} from '../../../common/utils/clone'

const initVenueLayout = {
    venueSize:{
      width: 16,
      height: 16,
    }
  }

const VenueLayout = ({props}) => {

  const boxContainer = useRef(null);


  const [venueLayoutState,setVenueLayoutState] = useState(initVenueLayout)
  const [boxStyle,setBoxStyle] = useState({
    "height": "100%",
    "width": "90%",
  })

  useEffect(() =>{
    // State did update
  });

  useEffect(() =>{
    // Component did mount
    console.log("Component did mount")
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateBox);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", updateBox);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // This state did update
    console.log("venueLayoutState did update",venueLayoutState)
    updateBox()
  }, [venueLayoutState]);

  const updateBox = () => {
    console.log("updateBox",venueLayoutState.venueSize.width,":",venueLayoutState.venueSize.height)

    let percentage = (venueLayoutState.venueSize.height/venueLayoutState.venueSize.width) * 100
    if(percentage > 100){
      percentage = 100
    }
    percentage = percentage+"%"

    // console.log("percentage",percentage)

    const cloneBoxStyle = clone(boxStyle)

    cloneBoxStyle.width = "100%"
    cloneBoxStyle.height = percentage
    setBoxStyle(cloneBoxStyle)

    // console.log("boxContainer",boxContainer)
    // console.log("height",boxContainer.current.clientHeight)
    // console.log("width",boxContainer.current.clientWidth)

  }



  const venueSizeRatioOnChange = (widthArg,heightArg) => {
    let width = (widthArg === null) ? venueLayoutState.venueSize.width : widthArg;
    let height = (heightArg === null) ? venueLayoutState.venueSize.height : heightArg;

    const cloneVenueLayoutState = clone(venueLayoutState);
    cloneVenueLayoutState.venueSize.width = width
    cloneVenueLayoutState.venueSize.height = height

    setVenueLayoutState(cloneVenueLayoutState)
  }

  const render = () => {
    console.log("render",venueLayoutState.venueSize.width,":",venueLayoutState.venueSize.height)
    // updateBox()
    const enlargeClass = (props.enlarge) ? " enlarge" : "" ;

    return (
      <div className={"venue-layout"+enlargeClass} >
        <div className="venue-layout-tools-top">
          Venue Size Ratio 
          <input 
            type="number" 
            value={venueLayoutState.venueSize.width} 
            onChange={(e) => {venueSizeRatioOnChange(e.target.value,null)}}/>
          by
          <input 
            type="number" 
            value={venueLayoutState.venueSize.height} 
            onChange={(e) => {venueSizeRatioOnChange(null,e.target.value)}}/>

          <button className="button close" onClick={props.toggleVenueLayout}>
            Close
          </button>
        </div>

        <div className="venue-layout-container">
          <div className="venue-layout-tools-side">
            side tools
          </div>
          <div className="venue-layout-box-container" ref={boxContainer}>
            <div className="venue-layout-box" style={boxStyle}>
              {boxStyle.height} x {boxStyle.width}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return render();
};

export default VenueLayout;
```

Comment: Good catch on the resize cleanup. forgot about that. I moved it outside of the component but that didn't fix it. I wonder if I'll need global state to tackle this problem?

Comment: It is the venueLayoutState that keeps changing back right I just assumed from your post.

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Can't figure out why it's doing that